# How do I share a "notes" section between my "Edit" and "Details" pages?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor

I have a simple Asp.Net MVC Core app (a "to-do list").  Each "Todo" item has zero or more "Notes".

**PROBLEM:**

I've copied/pasted the same "Notes" section into both my Edit and Details .cshtml pages.  It would be nice if I could write the .cshtml for "Notes" once, and simply "include" it in both pages.

I tried using partial classes ... but because the model in each parent page is different, it didn't work:

Edit.cshtml:

```
@page
@model Todo.Pages.EditModel
@using Todo.Pages.TodoList
...
<div>
  <!-- I want to do something like this... -->
  <partial name="notes_history" />
</div>
```

notes_history.cshtml:

```
@model Todo.Pages.EditModel

<div class="form-group card">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h4>Todo List History</hr>
    <table class="table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.TodoItem.Notes[0].CreatedDate)</th>
          <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.TodoItem.Notes[0].Text)</th>
          ...
      <tbody>
        @foreach (var note in model.TodoItem.Notes)
        {
          <tr>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => note.CreatedDate)</th>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => note.Text)</th>
          ...
```

This will work fine with my "Edit" page ... but it fails with "Details" .. or with any other page I might want to include "Notes history" in.

How can I make this work with partial classes?  Or what different Asp.Net Core feature can I use to share "notes" between my "Edit". "Details" (and possibly other) parent pages?

Comment: You need to create PartialView for displaying notes... and then render the partial view in both Edit and Details page.

Comment: Q: Isn't what I showed above already a "PartialView"?  If not, what's the difference  between what I'm doing and a "PartialView"? Q: where does the partial view get its data from? How does the "child view" read model data from the parent page (e.g. the Notes History in "Edit.cshtml.cs")? Q: Can you point me to any examples?

Comment: pardon me... it was not clear to me. The partial view can have its own model type. Example List of Notes. You an render the partial view from the main view. The model of main view can have a property which is a list of notes. So when main view renders the partial view, it can pass it to partial view by doing model.Property.  There are more than one ways you can render partial view from main view... https://dotnettutorials.net/lesson/different-ways-to-render-partial-view-in-mvc/

Comment: Beautiful - exactly what I was looking for.  Thank you.  I'll try it out, and let you know what happens.  Q: Would you mind writing this into a response?  I'd be happy to "upvote" and "accept" it once I've got everything working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare the model type for Partial view. This will be the data which you want to display in the partial view.

Conventionally partial view names start with `_`. So let say partial view for showing notes is named as `_NotesList.cshtml`.

```
@model List<Todo.Pages.Note>

<div class="form-group card">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h4>Todo List History</hr>
     <table class="table">
       <thead>
         <tr>
           <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model[0].CreatedDate)</th>
           <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model[0].Text)</th>
           ...
         </tr>
       </thead>
          <tbody>
            @foreach (var note in Model)
            {
              <tr>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => note.CreatedDate)</th>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => note.Text)</th>
                ...
```

Now following is one of the ways how you can use the partial view in main view.

Edit.cshtml

```
@page
@model Todo.Pages.EditModel
@using Todo.Pages.TodoList
...
<div>
    <!-- I want to do something like this... -->
    @{Html.RenderPartial("_NotesList", Model.Notes);}
</div>
```

Here the expectation is to have a property `Notes` in EditModel class as following.

```
public class EditModel
{
    ....
    public List<Note> Notes {get;set;}
    ....
}
```

I hope this will help you solve your issue.

Comment: It worked like a charm - thank you!  Thank you, too, for the tip about "_mypartial.cshtml" naming convention!